# Missing Reminders since upgrade to Catalina beta

Tags: macos, icloud, reminders, beta, catalina

I am using macOS 10.14.5 and all but one of my reminder lists have gone.

I have macOS Catalina Beta installed on a separate testing partition and all my Reminders are there. But they don't appear on my main partition.

Is there any way I can get them back?

I don't have any iOS devices. And when I go to iCloud via the web, it just says Reminders coming soon. I tried restoring Reminders via iCloud on the web, but after the restore, they still aren't present on 10.14.5

Any ideas?

(Note: This question has also been posted [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250487631))

Comment: That sounds like they're not *gone* they're now in a newer format that Mojave can't read. This is one reason you don't ever use a beta on your working machine, or in this case, using your regular AppleID/iCloud account.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is there any way to downgrade or export them out? Even if I can export them as a text file, then I can just re-add them. It's also a bit odd, as one list is still available.

Comment: Still says "Coming soon" but this is the iCloud beta link in case it's there in the future - https://beta.icloud.com

Comment: I had the same issue, right after upgrading reminders they all disappeared (on the same device i was upgrading from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

Go to https://www.icloud.com/#settings

You can then select to restore Reminders. Restore back to the earliest date available and it will work again (Although you can no longer access them on iCloud via the web or any devices that have been upgraded to iOS 13/Catalina. Your restored Reminders will also no longer Sync with iOS 13/Catalina. See update below for workaround).

This will also cause Calendars to be restored, so before restoring, back up your calendars. You can also install a Google account on your Mac (Go to System Preferences > Accounts and enter your Google details) and copy your calendar events to the Google Account, which will keep them backed up.

**UPDATE:**
If you want to continue to use your Reminders and sync them between devices while still remaining on Mojave (or pre IOS 13), consider adding one of the following accounts to your devices. All these allow Reminders to continue to work after the upgrade even on Apple systems that cannot be upgraded to the new Reminders:

- Yahoo Account
- AOL Account
- Microsoft Exchange (you need an
  organization that provides Exchange accounts to do this, you cannot
  set one up yourself).

(Obviously, if you add one of these 3 accounts, you need to add your reminders to these accounts (and not your iCloud account), but you can do that from within the Reminders App. It's really easy to move things between Apple accounts and these accounts, so in minutes you can have everything working again).

Comment: I don't see a "Restore Reminders" button, only a "Restore Calendars" button. Is that the one?

Comment: @Winterflags I guess they must have changed it since this answer was written. You can try restore calendars, but be sure to back them up to a google account following the instructions in the answer.

Comment: I expect to lose all Reminders after downgrade from Catalina to Mojave (since they have warned me). Is it also expected to lose some Calender items? I found some events missing on a shared calendar.

Comment: @amdyes I do not know. But I would recommend copying your calendars to a Google account before upgrading/downgrading.

Comment: Probably goes without saying but this won't work if you don't do iCloud backups. There wasn't anything of significance lost, but I would have liked to keep using my iOS 9 iPad for testing. I didn't anticipate Apple *corrupting their own data*, that "update" button was really vague. I thought it meant "Upgrade [the list with new items from the server]" not "Upgrade [the whole thing in an incompatible way]"

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me to recover them was:

- open Xcode simulator
- run a iOS 12 device
- login to iCloud inside the simulator
- manually copy reminders from the simulator to the mac reminders app

Comment: Does it only sync across iOS 12 / Mojave devices, or it also sync to iOS 13 / Catalina devices (just like you haven't upgraded Reminders), or it does not sync at all?

Comment: I doesn't sync at all, last step is to copy them manually

Answer (score 2):

macOS Catalina and iOS 13 brings a completely rebuilt Reminders app, which requires a new database. On first launch of Reminders the database will be upgraded. Upgraded iCloud reminders cannot be viewed on devices running macOS prior to Catalina and iOS prior to 13. Currently, as both macOS Catalina and iOS 13 are in beta, upgraded reminders are not available on iCloud.com either.

> Be aware that many of the new features in Reminders require a format change that prevents syncing with other copies of Reminders running in Mojave and iOS 12.
>
> [image: Upgrade Reminders]

https://tidbits.com/2019/06/24/apple-releases-public-betas-of-macos-10-15-catalina-ios-13-ipados-13-and-tvos-13/

Comment: Is there any way to downgrade or export them out? Even if I can export them as a text file, then I can just re-add them.  It's also a bit odd, as one list is still available.

Comment: This is correct …but doesn't answer the question.  
This does https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364870/8162