# Restore missing Reminders items after macOS Catalina

Tags: icloud, reminders, catalina

My Reminders lists and items are completely messed up after using macOS Catalina's upgrade helper.

- Completed items from a year ago are popping back (some from 2018)
- Move items are moved back to the old list
- Items ordering are all wrong

I don't know how Apple manages to get this so wrong: I had 4 active devices and they are all properly synced through iCloud (all have the same, latest Reminders data), so I can't imagine how Apple could upgrade using some legacy copy of my data.

Anyway, I have read [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364607/missing-reminders-since-upgrade-to-catalina-beta/364870#364870) but the same "Restore Reminders" options is no longer at icloud.com settings page. I only see "Restore Calendars", it doesn't mention Reminders.

Furthermore, the new Reminders app on macOS Catalina no longer allow  exporting or importing iCalendar format (`.ics` files), so everything I do now is high risk.

**Please let me know if there is any way I can get my Reminders data back. As `.ics` format, or something I can take screenshots and manually re-add.**

(I will try the iOS 12 Simulator option mentioned in above question later today ...)

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210220 This doesn't provide restoring help, but about what to expect in new reminders app if there's a sync mismatch.

Comment: This is infuriating, my reminders have been requiring an upgrade for years at this point, and I still can't get to them.  They aren't accessible on icloud.com either, I get the identical "requires upgrade" message there.  My mac with Catalina can't access them, my iPhone on iOS14 can't access them, and icloud.com can't access them.  Bravo Apple, bra-vo.